# How do you autopublish with FB.UI?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the stream_publish permission but it still pops up a dialog and there doesn't seem to be any way to pass in an autopublish bool (like it was before the graph api).

EDIT: Also tried offline_access with stream_publish.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
function streamPublish(imageUrl, imageHref, attachName, attachHref, attachCaption) {
 FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: '',
     attachment: {
       name: attachName,
       caption: attachCaption,
       description: (
         ''
       ),
       href: attachHref,
       media: [
         {
           type: 'image',
           href: imageHref,
           src: imageUrl
         }
        ]
     }
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       //alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       //alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/jssdk/learning_jssdk_12.html

The following will autopublish if you have the permissions unlike FB.UI :)

```
function publishPost(session) {
   var publish = {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'is learning how to develop Facebook apps.',
     picture : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/facebook/demoapp_jssdk/img/logo.gif',
     link : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/facebook/demoapp_jssdk/',
     name: 'This is my demo Facebook application (JS SDK)!',
     caption: 'Caption of the Post',
     description: 'It is fun to write Facebook App!',
     actions : { name : 'Start Learning', link : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/index.php'}
   };

   FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {  
       document.getElementById('confirmMsg').innerHTML = 
              'A post had just been published into the stream on your wall.';
   });
};
```

Comment: You should note that pre-filling 'message' in the publish object like in the above code would break Facebook policy so don't do it in live apps.

Comment: @Jont is correct. However, if the "message" has been supplied by the user (and they are aware that the message will be published - e.g. via checking a checkbox). Then you could use this method without breaking Facebook Policy.

Comment: I am having problems publishing content to facebook from my app. I am not able to publish content as ato publish. Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: @jestro, I am going to use this solution but got error and i have done app setting is their any other setting for app please lets us know. Thanks
**ERROR**
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}`