# Auto publish post after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need post published to facebook timeline automatically if checkbox checked.

I found some helpful resource which one [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396269/how-do-you-autopublish-with-fb-ui).

This code show success message but not published any post on my timeline.

```
function publishPost(session) {
    var publish = {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: 'is learning how to develop Facebook apps.',
        picture : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/facebook/demoapp_jssdk/img/logo.gif',
        link : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/facebook/demoapp_jssdk/',
        name: 'This is my demo Facebook application (JS SDK)!',
        caption: 'Caption of the Post',
        description: 'It is fun to write Facebook App!',
        actions : { name : 'Start Learning', link : 'http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/index.php'}
    };

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {  
       document.getElementById('confirmMsg').innerHTML = "Post published";
    });
};
```

Where is the actual fault.

Look below form when user check the box then post automatically on his timeline.

[I need look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1O6.png)

Comment: Do you have initialization of FB API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.8

Comment: Yes I have @kcp

Comment: that thread is from 2010 and the code is very old. please take a look at the official docs instead. also, do some debugging if something does not work (console.log will help you there).

Comment: btw, autoposting is not allowed, and you are not allowed to prefill the message, it must be 100% user generated. you must read the platform policy before creating any app.

Comment: @luschn Please check image from post, just updated this post

Comment: ok, but why not just use the feed or share dialog then? is the user already authorized with publish_actions? what does the debugging say?